# web application and mobile app automation testing together with selenium/appium

Tags: selenium, testing, synchronization, appium

I am new to selenium and appium.I have done automation script for mobile app.In my application There is two-side communications from the server  to the mobile client  and from the mobile client to the server.

How to test synchronously between  backend application and mobile client(android and ios)?
Is it possible? please advice me. Thanking you in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this saucelabs tutorial: https://saucelabs.com/mobile/selenium-mobile

Comment: i have already build script for mobile testing. i want to know how to do it mutually with web app.